# Storing objects in memcached and still loading them from the database

Tags: mysql, object, memcached, kohana

I have a problem with memcached.

I have the following code:

```
/**
* Load the char object
* @param char_id id char
* @return $char object
*/

function get_info( $char_id )
{
    $cache = Cache::instance(); 
    $cachetag = Kohana::config( 'medeur.environment' ) . '-charinfo_' . $char_id . '_obj' ;
    kohana::log('debug', "-> Getting $cachetag from CACHE..." ); 

    $char = $cache -> get( $cachetag );

    if ( is_null( $char ) )
    {
        kohana::log('debug', "-> Getting $cachetag from DB."); 
        $char = ORM::factory('character', $char_id );

        if ( !$char -> loaded )
            $char = null;

        $cache -> set( $cachetag, $char, 3600 );

    }

    return $char;

}
```

I see in the logfile that the object $char is taken from the cache:

```
2012-12-08 18:24:07 +01:00 --- debug: -> Getting test-global_adminmessage from CACHE...
2012-12-08 18:24:07 +01:00 --- debug: -> Getting test-charinfo_1_obj from CACHE...
```

However i keep seeing in the profiler table that i am still going on the database:

```
SELECT `characters`.* FROM (`characters`) WHERE `characters`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `characters`.`id` ASC LIMIT 0, 1
```

Why? in this case, the memcached it would be useless...

Comment: I assume you **also** see this message in the log? `debug', "-> Getting $cachetag from DB.`

Comment: Only the first time there is the message, When the object is cached i can't see the line $cachetag from DB. The caching works but it seems that when i get the object from the cache, the framework still goes on the database to reconstruct the object. This happen also if i store result sets. If i store an object or a resultset as an array, all is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked with the guys at Kohana. Kohana 2.x ORM class is not cacheable. It is cacheable on framework version 3.x

Answer (score 0):

Your *"Getting nnnn from CACHE..."* logging statement will always show up, regardless of whether or not you actually retrieve anything from the cache.  Consider moving it into an `else` statement after the large `if` block.

```
if(is_null($char)){
    ....
}
else {
    kohana::log('debug', "-> Got $cachetag from CACHE..." );
}
```